# How to scroll a JTable to a specific value?

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jtable

I have a `JTable` displaying the contents of a log file, and the first column is a timestamp with milliseconds (e.g. 10:31:54.531). 
The data is already ordered by this column.
I would like to allow the user to **scroll to the timestamp** he is interested in.

Here is a Java snippet of what I would like to do:

```java
String myTimestamp = "10:31:54.531";
Integer myRowIndex = getRowIndexFromStringTimestamp(myTimestamp);
myJTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(myRowIndex, myRowIndex);
myJTable.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(myJTable.getCellRect(myRowIndex, 0, true)));
```

But how to implement **`getRowIndexFromStringTimestamp`**?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a reference to the table and use a combination `JTable#getRowCount`, `JTable#getValueAt`

```
int matchIndex = -1;
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < myJTable.getRowCount(); index++) {
    Object value = myJTable.getValueAt(rowIndex, colIndex);
    if (value.equals(timestamp)) { // Or what ever comparison you need..
        matchIndex = rowIndex;
        break;
    } 
}
return matchIndex;
```

The problem with this is will get slower with more data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. The users should not load more than 150k rows, which is roughly 1 day of data (it's easier for them to load the entire day and then jump at different point in time)

Comment: Wouldn't a binary search be appropriate? The entries are sorted after all.

Comment: @lhballoti Assuming the data in the model was sorted, yes.

Comment: I just tried it (no binary search) and the performance is fast on 150k rows, so that works for me!

Answer (score 3):

- I think to [use Filtering instead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), is easiest than looping and searching in `XxxTableModel` or `JTables view` for comparing the desired value
- have to set proper [ColumnClass for (java.util.Date)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6233119/714968) for column contains `Date(DateTime`) value
- otherwise have to loop and search in `XxxTableModel` or `JTables view`, with comparing the value

Comment: Thank you! I shall try the filtering and get one row index (in model) after filtering,  then I can remove the filtering and scroll to this row index I guess