# Calling Previous Model Behavior of JTable.setModel()

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Have one `JTable` on my swing screen. While loading screen, I am setting one table model which is created for this table only.
And at run time if there is any data change I am recreating the same model and again set it using `objJTable.setModel(objCustTableModel)`.

Now the problem is table model which is loaded at the time of screen load, same model object get called while setting `objJTable.setModel(objCustTableModel)` at run time which called getColumnClass(int col) method from `CustTableModel` class. After this object call, my new model object get called. Again if I set another new 
table model, by using same code `objJTable.setModel(objCustTableModel2)`, model call's functions get called first from `objCustTableModel` and then 
`objCustTableModel2`.

In short `setModel()` function first call previous model object and then current model object. How can I restrict to call of previous model object?

For example

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;


/**
 * Steps to reproduce issue.
 * 1. Run this program.
 * 2. There will be two rows in table. Delete all rows one by one.
 * 3. Now click on Add button and see the exception.
 * 
 * I come to know that this exception is because of table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true); line, which is there in TestCustTableModel's constructor
 * If you comment this line, then issue got resolved.
 * But I want to apply sorting on columns so this line is required.
 */

public class TestCustTableModel extends JPanel{
    JTable table = new JTable();
    public TestCustTableModel() {

        Object[][] data = new Object[2][3];
        data[0][0] = "1";
        data[0][1] = "User1";
        data[0][2] = "Delete";

        data[1][0] = "2";
        data[1][1] = "User2";
        data[1][2] = "Delete";

        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
        addButton.addMouseListener(new AddListener());
        table.setModel(new CustModel(data));
        table.addMouseListener(new TableListener());

        /**#################################
         * Following line throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Please comment or Uncomment following line and see the difference.
         */
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);


        table.getTableHeader().setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        this.add(addButton);
        this.add(scrollPane);
    }


    class TableListener extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evnt) {
            Point p = evnt.getPoint();
            if(table.columnAtPoint(p) == 2) {
                Object[][] data = null;
                if(table.getModel().getRowCount() == 2 && table.rowAtPoint(p) == 0) {
                    data = new Object[1][3];
                    data[0][0] = "2";
                    data[0][1] = "User2";
                    data[0][2] = "Delete";
                }else if(table.getModel().getRowCount() == 2 && table.rowAtPoint(p) == 1) {
                    data = new Object[1][3];
                    data[0][0] = "1";
                    data[0][1] = "User1";
                    data[0][2] = "Delete";
                }else {
                    data = new Object[0][];
                }
                table.setModel(new CustModel(data));
            }
        }
    }


    class AddListener extends MouseAdapter{

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evnt) {
            if(table.getModel().getRowCount() == 2) {
                return;
            }
            Object[][] data = new Object[table.getModel().getRowCount() + 1][3];
            for(int i = 0; i <= table.getModel().getRowCount(); i++) {
                data[i][0] = i;
                data[i][1] = "User" + i;
                data[i][2] = "Delete";
            }
            table.setModel(new CustModel(data));
        }

    }

    class CustModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = {"ID", "NAME", "DELETE"};
        private Object[][] data = null;

        public CustModel(Object[][] data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }

        public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
            return getValueAt(0, col).getClass();
        }
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("SwapTableModel");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestCustTableModel obj = new TestCustTableModel();
        obj.display();
    }
}
```

at this time swing first internally called `getColumnClass` function on the basis of `objCustTableModel` and after that 
using `objCustTableModel2` object. I want to restrict call which is on the basis of `objCustTableModel`.

Comment: Post some code instead of describing your code in english (which I am unable to understand so far). Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and show us where you are stuck.

Comment: please whats `Override following function to show buttons` do you want to show JButtons in JTable, then is stored String value as description for JButton in model, really what do you want to do ....

Comment: *"edited question"*  Where is the SSCCE?

Comment: @mKorbel, I have added some icons in `JTable` for edit and delete selected row, which is working fine.

Comment: then to add Icon to the XxxTableModel directly

Comment: @mKorbel, Thanks for suggetion, but my problem is I just `setModel()`  call `getColumnClass()` function with new model object only and not with privious one. Please see below answer which is suggested by "trashgod".

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I have created one SSCCE. How can I send it on forum?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Added Example in question and explain to reproduce issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8260663/230513), I saw no unexpected behavior with the `getColumnClass()` implementation shown below.

```
private Model() {
    final Object[] data = {this.toString()};
    this.model = new DefaultTableModel(data, 1){

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            System.out.println(data[0]);
            return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
        }
    };
    model.addRow(data);
}
```

Note that `JTable` may invoke `getColumnClass()` anytime it determines that a cell needs rendering. If necessary, you can use `EventQueue.invokeLater()` to schedule something that will "happen after all pending events are processed."

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Addenda:

- If `getAutoCreateRowSorter()` is `true`, `setModel()` tries to restore the `RowSorter` created using the old model.
- You can specify `setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)` *after* you change models, as shown below, or extend your `TableModel` to update the model in place, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11241218/230513).
- Use `ActionListener` for `JButton` instead of `MouseListener`.
- Use a `TableCellEditor` for buttons in the table, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5556631/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5559747/230513).

Code:

```
addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (table.getModel().getRowCount() == 2) {
            return;
        }
        Object[][] data = new Object[table.getModel().getRowCount() + 1][5];
        table.setRowSorter(null);
        for (int i = 0; i <= table.getModel().getRowCount(); i++) {
            data[i][0] = i;
            data[i][6] = "User" + i;
            data[i][7] = "Delete";
        }
        table.setModel(new CustModel(data));
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Trashgod, I have check with example which you suggested. If you just debug the same example(to view object ids) you can see, as you change dropdown value, `setModel()` first calls `getColumnClass()` function from old object and at second time it calles from new model object. And thats my problem. I just want to call `getColumnClass()` function only with new model object only.

Comment: @Navnath  [you can to hardocde getColumnClass](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6233119/714968)

Comment: @mKorbel There is nothing to do with `getColumnClass()`. It's all about, functions from model class getting called twice when I set new model to table by using `setModel()` function. mKorbel, Thanks that you are following this thread, Please suggest me something.

Comment: Using Java 6, I break on `setModel()` and then break on `getColumnClass()`; I'm seeing access _only_ to the new model.

Comment: @Navnath see  [quite good AbstractTableModel as starting point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6901508/714968), be sure that  [author of this answers published some of great code...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513+[jtable]+abstracttablemodel+), please I'm still not sure about your real issue, aren't clear for me or ???

Comment: @mKorbel, I have created one SSCCE. How can I send it on forum?

Comment: @mKorbel, Added Example in question and explain to reproduce issue

Comment: Yes. But I have more data which got modify. That's the reason I am changing data model itself instead to modify each cell one by one.

Comment: @Navnath this issue is valid for all Listeners and notifiers added to JTable or its Model, have to remove all those Object before switching to new or another XxxTableModel, becuase these references are still valid, then there is concurency betweens model, that generating any possible exceptions, btw good question, my +1

Comment: @Navnath this is reason for why we asking for SSCCE in all cases, simple never ending ...., phaaaaa as you can to see on this post :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
 DefaultTableModel model ;
    /** Creates new form DynRowAdd */
    public DynRowAdd() {
        initComponents();
          model = new DefaultTableModel();
                    jTable1.setModel(model);
                    model.addColumn("Id");
                    model.addColumn("First Name");
                    model.addColumn("Last Name");
                    model.addColumn("Company Name");
    }
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        model.addRow(new Object[]{jTextField1.getText(), jTextField2.getText(),jTextField3.getText(),jTextField4.getText()});

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before, as i was calling jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(),col) in jtable's ListSelectionListener, and after changing the jtable's model, it was throwing invalid index, out of bound exception, after calling jTable.setModel(Model) after a row selection, and it was solved by assuring that calling the value and the selected row getters - jTable.getValueAt(jTable.getSelectedRow(),col) - wasn't from an old events that they are still being made, by !event.getValueIsAdjusting() in the jtable's ListSelectionListener, and i understood by this question this notation, that it was to not trying to invoke the value and the selected row getters in the recalling of the old model in the jtable's set model calling - please if you have a better knowladge correct me if i was wrong or not precise - , and this is an example of my previous problem, you may try to comment the !event.getValueIsAdjusting() if condition, to see the notation :

```
package testingsetmodel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;


public class TestingSetModel extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ItemListener  {


    TestingSetModel() {                                

        init();        

    }

    private void init()
    {

        northPanel = new JPanel( );     // for adding jtable6
        eastPanel = new JPanel( );      // for adding jtable7
        southPanel = new JPanel( );     // for adding 2 jradiobuttons

        first = new JRadioButton("1st");               
        second = new JRadioButton("2nd", true);  

        rg = new ButtonGroup( ); 
        rg.add( first ) ;  rg.add( second ) ;                              

        first.addItemListener(this);        second.addItemListener(this); 

        jScrollPane6 = new JScrollPane();
        jScrollPane7 = new JScrollPane();

        northPanel.add(jScrollPane6);    eastPanel.add(jScrollPane7);
        southPanel.add(first);      southPanel.add(second);        

        jTable6 = new javax.swing.JTable(){
            DefaultTableCellRenderer renderRight = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();

            { // initializer block
                renderRight.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            }

            @Override
            public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer (int arg0, int arg1) {
                return renderRight;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                switch (col) {
                    case 0:
                    return false;
                    default:
                    return true;
                }
            }

        };

        jTable6.setAutoCreateRowSorter(false);

        jTable6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Traditional Arabic", 0, 19));

        jTable6.setEnabled(true);

        jTable6.setRowHeight(25);


        ((DefaultTableCellRenderer)jTable6.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
        jTable6.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jScrollPane6.setViewportView(jTable6);
        jTable6.setSelectionBackground(new Color(0,100,255,7)); // cutomize selection color
        jTable6.setSelectionForeground(Color.black);

        jTable6.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);

        setTheDefaultJTable6Model();

        if(jTable6.getRowCount()>0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<jTable6.getRowCount(); i++)
            {
                if(jTable6.getValueAt(i,0).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("4"))
                {
                    jTable6.setRowSelectionInterval(i, i);
                    jTable6.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(jTable6.getCellRect(i, 0, true)));
                }
            }
        }

        jTable7 = new javax.swing.JTable(){
            DefaultTableCellRenderer renderRight = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();

            { // initializer block
                renderRight.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            }

            @Override
            public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer (int arg0, int arg1) {
                return renderRight;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                switch (col) {
                    case 0:
                    return false;
                    default:
                    return true;
                }
            }

        };

        jTable7.setAutoCreateRowSorter(false);

        jTable7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Traditional Arabic", 0, 19));

        jTable7.setEnabled(true);

        jTable7.setRowHeight(25);

        jTable7.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        jScrollPane7.setViewportView(jTable7);
        jTable7.setSelectionBackground(new Color(0,100,255,7)); // cutomize selection color for lite one for writting under selection
        jTable7.setSelectionForeground(Color.black);

        jTable7.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);

        jTable6.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){


            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {

                // try to comment the following if condition, and setting the model through changing the jradiobuttons
                if(!event.getValueIsAdjusting() && jTable6.getSelectedRow() != -1 && jTable6.getSelectedRowCount() == 1)
                {

                    DefaultTableModel clinicsSpecsJtableModel = new DefaultTableModel(); // the model
                    Object[] clinicsSpecsJtableColumnsNames = new Object[2]; // the four showable columns from the jtable model
                    clinicsSpecsJtableColumnsNames[0] = "name" ;
                    clinicsSpecsJtableColumnsNames[1] = "address" ;
                    clinicsSpecsJtableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(clinicsSpecsJtableColumnsNames);
                    Object[] clinicsSpecsJtableRowData = new Object[2];
                    ArrayList<String> clinicsNames = new ArrayList<>();
                    ArrayList<String> clinicsAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
                    clinicsNames.add("J34hp "+jTable6.getValueAt(jTable6.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                    clinicsNames.add("J34df "+jTable6.getValueAt(jTable6.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                    clinicsNames.add("J34as "+jTable6.getValueAt(jTable6.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                    clinicsNames.add("J34gh "+jTable6.getValueAt(jTable6.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                    clinicsNames.add("J45hj "+jTable6.getValueAt(jTable6.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                    clinicsNames.add("J56gr "+jTable6.getValueAt(jTable6.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                    clinicsNames.add("J34mn "+jTable6.getValueAt(jTable6.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                    clinicsNames.add("J56vr "+jTable6.getValueAt(jTable6.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                    clinicsNames.add("J45pi "+jTable6.getValueAt(jTable6.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                    clinicsAddresses.add("21 Tmk st");
                    clinicsAddresses.add("13 bcv st");
                    clinicsAddresses.add("67 rfb st");
                    clinicsAddresses.add("81 Tmk st");
                    clinicsAddresses.add("31 Tmk st");
                    clinicsAddresses.add("23 Jkl st");
                    clinicsAddresses.add("54 IUR st");
                    clinicsAddresses.add("51 Jkl st");
                    clinicsAddresses.add("71 rfb st");
                    for( int i=0 ; i<clinicsNames.size() ; i++ )
                    {

                        clinicsSpecsJtableRowData[0] = clinicsNames.get(i);
                        clinicsSpecsJtableRowData[1] = clinicsAddresses.get(i);

                        clinicsSpecsJtableModel.addRow(clinicsSpecsJtableRowData); // adding the row to the model

                    }
                    jTable7.setModel(clinicsSpecsJtableModel); // setting the model to the jtable
                    for (int column = 0; column < jTable7.getColumnCount(); column++)
                    {
                        TableColumn tableColumn = jTable7.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
                        int preferredWidth = tableColumn.getMinWidth();
                        int maxWidth = tableColumn.getMaxWidth();

                        for (int row = 0; row < jTable7.getRowCount(); row++)
                        {
                            TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = jTable7.getCellRenderer(row, column);
                            Component c = jTable7.prepareRenderer(cellRenderer, row, column);
                            int width = c.getPreferredSize().width + jTable7.getIntercellSpacing().width;
                            preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredWidth, width);

                            //  We've exceeded the maximum width, no need to check other rows

                            if (preferredWidth >= maxWidth)
                            {
                                preferredWidth = maxWidth;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        tableColumn.setPreferredWidth( preferredWidth );
                    }
                    jTable7.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Traditional Arabic", 0, 17)); // assure the column headers font and text size
                    ((DefaultTableCellRenderer)jTable7.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT); // align right
                    jTable7.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); // set single selection only enabled
                    jScrollPane7.setViewportView(jTable7); // draw jtable             

                }                       

            }

        });                                   

        Container cont = getContentPane();
        cont.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        cont.add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        cont.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // to close the JFrame        

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {

            JFrame f = new TestingSetModel();
            f.setSize(800, 600);    
            f.setVisible(true);        

        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JPanel northPanel, southPanel, eastPanel;                                   
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton first, second;
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup rg;                
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable6;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane6;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable7;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane7;

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

        if(first.isSelected())
        {

            setTheDefaultJTable6Model();
            removeJTable7Rows();


        }else if(second.isSelected())
        {

            setTheCustomizedJTable6Model();
            removeJTable7Rows();

        }


    }


    private void removeJTable7Rows()
    {

        DefaultTableModel defaultModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable7.getModel();
        defaultModel.setRowCount(0);        

    }    

    private void setTheDefaultJTable6Model()
    {

        DefaultTableModel numbersJtableModel = new DefaultTableModel(); // the model
        Object[] numbersJtableColumnsNames = new Object[1]; // the four showable columns from the jtable model
        numbersJtableColumnsNames[0] = "number" ;

        numbersJtableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(numbersJtableColumnsNames);
        Object[] numbersJtableRowData = new Object[1]; 
        ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        numbers.add("1");
        numbers.add("2");
        numbers.add("3");
        numbers.add("4");
        numbers.add("5");
        numbers.add("6");


        for( int i=0 ; i<numbers.size() ; i++ ) // feeding array of object with numbers data
        {
            numbersJtableRowData[0] = numbers.get(i);

            numbersJtableModel.addRow(numbersJtableRowData); // adding the row to the model

        }

        jTable6.setModel(numbersJtableModel); // setting the model to the jtable


        for (int column = 0; column < jTable6.getColumnCount(); column++)
        {
            TableColumn tableColumn = jTable6.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
            int preferredWidth = tableColumn.getMinWidth();
            int maxWidth = tableColumn.getMaxWidth(); 

            for (int row = 0; row < jTable6.getRowCount(); row++)
            {
                TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = jTable6.getCellRenderer(row, column);
                Component c = jTable6.prepareRenderer(cellRenderer, row, column);
                int width = c.getPreferredSize().width + jTable6.getIntercellSpacing().width;
                preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredWidth, width);

                //  We've exceeded the maximum width, no need to check other rows

                if (preferredWidth >= maxWidth)
                {
                    preferredWidth = maxWidth;
                    break;
                }
            }                    

            tableColumn.setPreferredWidth( preferredWidth );
        }

        jTable6.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Traditional Arabic", 0, 17)); // assure the column headers font and text size
        ((DefaultTableCellRenderer)jTable6.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT); // align right
        jTable6.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); // set single selection only enabled
        jScrollPane6.setViewportView(jTable6); // draw jtable


    }


    private void setTheCustomizedJTable6Model()
    {

        DefaultTableModel numbersJtableModel = new DefaultTableModel(); // the model
        Object[] numbersJtableColumnsNames = new Object[1]; // the four showable columns from the jtable model
        numbersJtableColumnsNames[0] = "number" ;

        numbersJtableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(numbersJtableColumnsNames);
        Object[] numbersJtableRowData = new Object[1]; 
        ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        numbers.add("10");
        numbers.add("20");
        numbers.add("30");
        numbers.add("40");
        numbers.add("50");
        numbers.add("60");


        for( int i=0 ; i<numbers.size() ; i++ ) // feeding array of object with numbers data
        {
            numbersJtableRowData[0] = numbers.get(i);

            numbersJtableModel.addRow(numbersJtableRowData); // adding the row to the model

        }

        jTable6.setModel(numbersJtableModel); // setting the model to the jtable


        for (int column = 0; column < jTable6.getColumnCount(); column++)
        {
            TableColumn tableColumn = jTable6.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
            int preferredWidth = tableColumn.getMinWidth();
            int maxWidth = tableColumn.getMaxWidth(); 

            for (int row = 0; row < jTable6.getRowCount(); row++)
            {
                TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = jTable6.getCellRenderer(row, column);
                Component c = jTable6.prepareRenderer(cellRenderer, row, column);
                int width = c.getPreferredSize().width + jTable6.getIntercellSpacing().width;
                preferredWidth = Math.max(preferredWidth, width);

                //  We've exceeded the maximum width, no need to check other rows

                if (preferredWidth >= maxWidth)
                {
                    preferredWidth = maxWidth;
                    break;
                }
            }                    

            tableColumn.setPreferredWidth( preferredWidth );
        }

        jTable6.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("Traditional Arabic", 0, 17)); // assure the column headers font and text size
        ((DefaultTableCellRenderer)jTable6.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT); // align right
        jTable6.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); // set single selection only enabled
        jScrollPane6.setViewportView(jTable6); // draw jtable


    }    

}
```

this example should changing the model of the jTable6 by selecting the other radio button in the radio buttons group, by setModel() method in the setTheDefaultJTable6Model() method. so in such we have a tied getting with the jtable model without assuring that it is not from any previous events where changes are still being made, we would get an exception after setting the model of the jtable to a new model